# Viewing exception/trace information for an Azure hosted NancyFX app

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, logging, nancy

I have several ASP.NET+NancyFX web applications hosted on Azure. Should I expect to see unhandled exceptions or uses of `System.Diagnostics.Trace` recorded in Azure logs anywhere? I've enabled Application Logs to the filesystem in Azure but no exception information is found in the files in LogFiles\Application (for example if I cause an unhandled `Nancy.RequestExecutionException`).